# Convergence of integrals for subsequence

Tags: lebesgue-integral

In an article I'm currently reading, a reasoning is used that I don't understand.

We have an integral of a function over a domain with both depending on the same $\epsilon>0$. They show that $$\displaystyle\int_{D_\epsilon}f_\epsilon g_\epsilon dx \to \displaystyle\int_{D}f_0 g_0 dx (*)$$

as $\epsilon\to 0$ (after passing to a subsequence/subfamily). For this they show that $f_\epsilon \to f_0$ in $L^p(D)$ and $g_\epsilon$ is bounded in $L^{p'}(D)$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$

Also we have that $\mathcal{L}^n(D\setminus D_\epsilon)$ vanishes. Then they say that a standard argument yields the claim. However I don't understand this. The thing missing for me is some convergence of the $g_\epsilon$ term. I have tried manipulating the first term above with some artificial zeros but something is missing. I would be happy about every help, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a source for this question ?

Comment: You may want to provide details to your question so that it makes sens and that people can actually understand it. This would be the first step for someone answering your question.

Comment: Hi, yes the source is a paper from Lindgren/Lindqvist called "On a comparison principle for Trudinger's equation" and it's in the proof of Theorem 1!

Comment: I assume they use that every bounded sequence in $L^p$ has a weakly convergent subsequence but I can't quite figure it out.
You may find the article here: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/acv-2019-0095/html